# How to Constantly call a function in a WPF application

Tags: wpf

I would like to constantly check if an xml file have been updated... I would like a create a function that is constantly being called even if it is every quarter of a second..

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            textBox.Text = "Count" + Count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26875/WPF-XmlDataProvider-Two-Way-Data-Binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve that using `async/await`

```
public async void Poll()
{
    while(true)
    {
        textBox.Text = "Count" + Count++;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
    }
}
```

To provide a cancel option provide a `CancellationToken`

```
while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
```

For further Information see the documentation for [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

**Without polling**, you can be warned of File system modifications,including subdirectories with `FileSystemWatcher`.

4 categories of events :
 - Created
 - Changed
 - Deleted
 - Renamed

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
watcher.Filter = "*.config";
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
    | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}
```